# Как копировать файлы из одной папки в другую, указав её полный путь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прошу мне помочь с решением проблемы. Представим ситуацию, что есть exe (скомпилированный .py файл) и папка "files", где находятся какие-либо файлы. А есть ещё папка "end", которая находится, к примеру, на другом локальном диске. Как скопировать через Python файлы из папки "files" и, указав полный путь (C:....), вставить это в папке "end" (если требуется, то с заменой). Это может пригодится на пример с установкой модов во всякие игры (GTA SA на пример). Просьба привести примеры и скинуть понятный материал по этому.
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение:

```
import os
import shutil

folder_from = r'otkuda'
folder_to = r'kuda'

for f in os.listdir(folder_from):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_from, f)):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(folder_from, f), os.path.join(folder_to, f))
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder_from, f)):
        os.system(f'rd /S /Q {folder_to}\\{f}')
        shutil.copytree(os.path.join(folder_from, f), os.path.join(folder_to, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятный вопрос. Вообще есть два пути. Первый запускать скрипт использую subprocces, [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079426/python-copy-file-using-subprocess) приведён подробный разбор как это делается. Либо просто используй архиватор в простонародье инстолятор.